# Something like |01 00 01 00| in the tcp packet about the snort rule?

Tags: networking, tcp, packet, snort

This is a snort rule:

```
alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"INFO web bug 0x0 gif attempt"; flow:from_server,established; content:"Content-type|3A| image/gif"; nocase; content:"GIF"; nocase; distance:0; content:"|01 00 01 00|"; distance:3; within:4; content:"|2C|"; distance:0; content:"|01 00 01 00|"; distance:4; within:4; classtype:misc-activity; sid:2925; rev:2;)
```

From the alert name, I can see it seems to preventing receive html code including 0x0 gif to avoid the bandwidth depletion. I just want to know what is something like `|01 00 01 00|` here. Please tell me to help me have a better understand of the whole rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`|01 00 01 00|` is width and height value of the GIF.

`content:"|01 00 01 00|"; distance:3; within:4;` matched 4bytes after `GIF89a`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Good luck~